# Why isn't there a 'delete' account button (for users with higher reputation)?

Tags: support, deleted-users

Why isn't there a 'delete' account button? My research shows me that there is one if that account hasn't answered any questions.

Comment: Um, why?  I can't say I've ever wanted to delete any account on any website.  It sounds like it would cause orders of magnitude more problems from accidental deletions than it would help.

Comment: Moderators don't delete accounts, you have to get a Stack Exchange team member to do that. And there is no "delete" button because they want to discourage account deletion for no reason (aka ragequitting), which causes far more heartache. I guess I'm in no position to argue with the premise of your question, since I am "one of those high reputation people", but I still question the validity of the assertion that everyone will eventually want to delete their account. *Why?* This isn't like Facebook, we don't share personal information, so there's really nothing to delete.

Comment: Usually the only users who want to delete their accounts are the ones who are question-banned, and they're looking to create another account in the hopes that they can bypass the ban. It's rather futile, given that Stack Exchange has the ability to ban entire IP addresses, if need be. Also, [there's work being done to turn complete bans intro throttling instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230899/163250), to encourage users to keep and improve their current accounts, instead of just deleting them and (unsuccessfully) trying to start over.

Comment: Still, I LIKE BUTTONS! +1, +reopenv

Comment: I don't see why this is closed. Asking why features are/are not implemented is a perfectly legit use of meta IMO.

Comment: @MartinSmith agreed, downvoting and closing a support question makes very little sense. Oh well.

Comment: @MartinSmith look at the [revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/260654/1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your research has hit on the answer, but the full answer.

From the users perspective:

- If the account has had no activity (given no votes) then it can be self deleted.

From the moderators perspective:

- If the account has had low activity (earned less than a certain amount of rep) then it can be deleted.

In all other cases it requires an employee to delete the account.

There are reasons why this is the case. The main one being that deleting accounts that have voted on posts causes the recipients of those votes to lose reputation. This is not a nice thing so should be done as a last resort.